# WPF Buttons ContentTemplate getting overridden when set through the style

Tags: c#, wpf

If I set `ContentTemplate` on Content Presenter directly it works fine, if I use `Style` it gets overridden:

Inside Buttons `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Default}"/>
```

vs

```
<ContentPresenter Style="{StaticResource MyContentStyle}"/>
```

Works fine:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Default">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>this is the</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>default view</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Default}"
                                      />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">Click Me</Button>
```

Default `DataTemplate` is not applied, it says overridden in visual tree.
    
        
            this is the
            default view

```
<Style x:Key="MyContentStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Default}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      Style="{StaticResource MyContentStyle}"
                                      />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">Click Me</Button>
```

If I use `ContentPresenter` independently from button it works fine:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Style="{StaticResource MyContentStyle}" Content="Work fine even with Style" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Button is odd.  I have seen the behavior myself.

Comment: It's all about precedence. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence
ContentPresenter uses DataTemplate property of parent as own template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` has its own `ContentTemplate` property. Set this one directly:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Default}">Click Me</Button>
```

Or in a `Style` that you apply to the `Button`:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" >
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Default}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Margin="20">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
...
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">Click Me</Button>
```

Comment: ContentTemplate does actually help me, because I was using style on Content presenter to switch between different ContentTemplates with a data trigger. Now I can apply DataTrigger for Content template in ButtonStyle rather than MyContentStyle :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If content is set on the ContentPresenter, the Style will be applied.
So the solution for style to work is:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  Style="{StaticResource MyContentStyle}" />
```